# Autocomplete not suggesting properly in kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

[Example of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyA3l.png)

As shown in the image, suggestion for above created variable is not showing, but if i create a new function then i can access the variable.

I have tried reinstalling android studio,invalidate cache and restart, deleted AndroidStudio folder inside AppData folder as well

Im using android studio bumblebee patch 3

Comment: Why do you expect the variable to show up there? You are not supposed to use a variable there.

Comment: https://imgur.com/Lqx5nWX  shouldn't it show the declared variable in this place? Im learning by watching youtube video and its suggesting for him

Comment: @SusanDahal on the top level of a class or object, all you can do is declare stuff: ``val``s, ``var``s, functions etc. You can't run any actual code there, besides expressions that are part of your variable declaration (like ``val hi = "hello" + " there"``). If there's some code that you need to run when the object's created, you can do it in an ``init`` block, otherwise it needs to go in a function

Answer (score 2):

You can not use a variable directly their, if you want to IDE to show suggestion their you can reinitialize your variable with other variable like

```
var name="hello"
var newName = na(here comes the suggetion)
```

here the suggestion with your above variable should show or if you call this variable from inside any function it will show

Comment: Thank you. I fooling didn't even think of it..